# Slavic second palatalization

Tags: slavic-languages, palatalization, interslavic

Why is the Slavic second palatalization took place before PIE *aj (Proto-Slavic *ě), but врагъ (vra**g**ŭ, enemy) / враѕи (vra**dz**i, enemies), where vradz**i** is a PIE *ey (Proto-Slavic *i)?

Comment: @AlexB. The Slavic second palatalization did not take place before Proto-Slavic *e. The Slavic second palatalization did take place before Proto-Slavic *ě (ě₂)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably took the description of the second Slavic palatalization from some simplified description. It isn't the case that it would only happen before *ě* (yat') and not before *i*. It happened before both.

The ě and i were the results of the monophthongization of *oi or *ai (if these two were actually distinguished at all). In [Monophthongization of diphthongs in Proto-Slavic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monophthongization_of_diphthongs_in_Proto-Slavic) you can read:

> While most cases of older *ai developed into *ě₂, some inflectional
> endings appear to have developed *i₂ instead. It is unclear what
> factors are involved in triggering one reflex versus the other.
>
> -The o-stem nominative plural (Old Church Slavonic člověkъ, člověci), reflecting the original Proto-Indo-European pronominal
> ending *-oy, also seen in Lithuanian -ai.
> -The thematic imperative infix (Old Church Slavonic rešti, rekǫ, reci), reflecting the original Proto-Indo-European infix *-oyh₁-.

So [*wargai](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Balto-Slavic/warg%C3%A1s) > vordzi > vradzi (vorodzi, vrazi,...) in the same way as člověci (Lith. [vaikaĩ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vaikas#Lithuanian)).

Comment: I didn't know about i₂ before asking. I did know, that most cases of PIE *ei developed into PS *i (*i₁). Thanks a lot